# post any checked chekbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i updated code and this is the corect solution of  problem

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]           
    public ActionResult Edit(int[] rb, int id)
    {
        List<nastava_prisustvo> nastava = new List<nastava_prisustvo>();

        string poruka = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <=rb.Length; i++)
        {
            string name = "chk" + i;
            string selID = Request.Form[name];  

            if (selID == "on")
            {
               //poruka = poruka + "Polje sa rednim brojem "+ i +" je chekirano\n";

                nastava.Add(new nastava_prisustvo
               {
                br_indexa = int.Parse(Request.Form["id_stud"+i]),
                id_predmet = id
               });
            }
        }
       // ViewData["Message"] = poruka;
        return View("show", nastava);
    }
```

View:

```
 <table class="data-table">        
    <tr> 
         <th>
            Redni br.
        </th>
        <th>
            Br. Indexa
        </th>
        <th>
            Prezime
        </th>
        <th>
            Ime
        </th>
        <th>
           <input id="check_all" type="checkbox" onclick="function" />
        </th>  
    </tr>

<% int rb = 1;%>
<% foreach (var item in Model)
   { %>

    <tr>
    <td>
            <input readonly="readonly" class="input-box" id="rb" type="text" name="rb"  value="<%= Html.Encode(rb)%>" />
        </td>

        <td>

            <input readonly="readonly" class="input-box" id="id_stud" type="text" name="id_stud"  value="<%= Html.Encode(item.id_stud)%>" />

        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.prezime)%>
        </td>
        <td>
             <%= Html.Encode(item.ime)%>
        </td>
         <td>
           <input id="check"  name="chk<%= Html.Encode(rb)%>" type="checkbox"  /> 
        </td>
    </tr>

<% rb = rb + 1;%>
<% } %>

</table>
```

Comment: Above is the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example demonstrates how to pass checkbox's value to controller.

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
        <form action="/home/index" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="value1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="value2" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(string cb)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = cb;

        return View();
    }
```

This example demonstrates how to receive via array.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(string[] cb)
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (string value in cb)
            result += value.ToString() + " ";
        ViewData["Message"] = result;

        return View();
    }


   <form action="/home/index" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="v1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="v2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="v3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="v4" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Seems like that would work ok for a radio, but a checkbox can get multiple values posted back.  You might need to receive it as an array of the expected type.

Comment: By default, only checkbox in "On" state will be posted to server.

Comment: When write  if (check[j]=="on") I have this error:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: If these checkbox share the same name, only one of these value can be posted. 

If they are in the format of name[0], name[1], etc to construct an array parameter, the default modal binder may return null for this parameter if posted items' name are non-continuous.

So, it may require some tricks.

Comment: You got this error because there're no more than j items are posted to server. But we can't tell the reason from your server side code. It depends on how you wrote the html page and which items did you check.

Comment: html code for checkbox in my aspx page:

<input  name="check" type="checkbox"  />

Comment: This way, your check parameter can only have one element or be null.

Comment: I updated the example, but note as I stated previously, you must select all checkboxs to run the example.

Comment: how to dynamically add a number in parentheses

Comment: <% for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { %>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Items[<%= i %>]" /> 
<% } %>

Comment: I created the name in your instructions but still have the old problem in line: if (check[j] =="On")

error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The example requires you select all items to work. Refer to my previous explanations.

Comment: I updated code and everything works as you said. Just need a trick of which you speak

Comment: Why then this code does not work when I not select all checkbox

Comment: Because the default ModalBinder can't handle the situation as you expect.

Comment: Does this mean that it should change default ModalBinder

Comment: not necessarily, because we can get over it with code in most recent example. it's a problem exists in our old sample code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of checkboxes and you want to pass the checked ones to the controller, all you need to do is the following:

name of each check box in the view "items"

controller Action:

```
 public ActionResult(UpdateObject updateobject)
 {
      string[] list = updateobject.items;
 }
```

Update object definition:

```
 public class UpdateObject
 {
      public string[] items { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: i was just showing you that you can create a bunch of checkboxes in a view and give them the same name and when you post your form, you can have an array of the checked ones passed into your controller action